# Updating a SQL-Server DB on another DB update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

I have 2 different SQL-Server Databases. For the sake of the example let's call them Test1 and Test2. I would like to write a command that will update tables in Test2 (Trigger, SP or any other idea you fellows might have) once data is being extracted from Test1.

Comment: Have you tried anything in regards with triggers on 'Test1' and wrote the trigger so that it tried to do something on 'Test2'? If you did, did you get any errors? Show us some work and explain what is not working

Comment: No I haven't tried it because I have no idea on how to operate a cross-db trigger.

Comment: Do you want to update Test2 database as a result of runing a SELECT statement on Test1?

Comment: Nope. Test1 is a DB operated by a software. I want to update Test2 as a result of the software opening Test1 for reading (I have access to Test1 as an admin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You Can Create Trigger For Another DataBase:
```

Here `Db_Test1` and `DB_Test2` is two different database.

`[dbo].[Table1]`:table from `Db_Test1`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
)
```

`[dbo].[Table_1]`:table from `[DB_Test2`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Fk_Id] [bigint] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

> And Here is the Trigger for update on [Db_Test1].[dbo].[Table1]

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgAfterUpdate] ON  [dbo].[Table1]
FOR Update
AS
     declare @id int
    declare @name varchar(100)
    declare @comments varchar(100)

    select @id=id from inserted i
    select @name=i.name from inserted i
    set @comments='hello'   

    if update(name)
    update  [DB_Test2].[dbo].[Table_1] set Name=@name where Fk_Id=@id
```